# Use Flash to save and read data within a SharePoint site

Tags: asp.net, flash, sharepoint, flv

I'm a complete newbie to SharePoint and I've been tasked to develop a SharePoint site with Flash content (Flash CS3 or CS5). I've done some quick research on this and I understand there are different ways to query SharePoint. I must say it's been a long process for me to try to piece different bits of information to achieve what I'm asked to do.

So here it is.

- Develop a site using SharePoint 2007 with Flash content.
- User input in the Flash objects will be stored.
- Previous user input will be retrieved and displayed in the Flash objects for reviewing
  purpose.
- User input will later be processed/manipulated for reporting purposes.
- Embed FLV videos on certain pages.

I understand data can be saved as lists in SharePoint and you can create custom ASPX to get the lists and parse it as XML input for a Flash object. Can I reverse this process when it comes to saving data?

What would be the best approach to implement the above requirements in SharePoint 2007 environment?

Or, should I consider saving data in an external DB, say MSSQL, and having custom ASPX query that DB and generate XML for Flash objects?

Or maybe any APIs that can make this process easier?

Any suggestion or leads to resources will be much appreciated!
And please give your answers for a SharePoint beginner like me.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I've ever developed with Flash... and would choose not to for that matter. But if you need it to integrate with SharePoint lists, the easiest way may be using web services. Read away:
[SharePoint Web Services Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878586%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks very much, Nigel, for the link to the SharePoint Reference. I personally would not use Flash for this task, but Flash objects were already developed elsewhere and to be dumped inside SharePoint. So I'm still looking for ways to achieve my requirements.